# Do I need to get API Key for Google Book search

Tags: google-books

I am little bit confused interpreting the Google Book API terms. [In this page](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using) it is written that

> Note: Performing a search does not require authentication, so you do
>   not have to provide the Authorization HTTP header with the GET
>   request. However, if the call is made with authentication, each Volume
>   will include user-specific information, such as purchased status.

Does that mean I don't need to use an API key for searching book info or linking cover from google books (to be used in Android App)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For searching only the informations about books (author, title, etc..) you can write code without have any API key. But probably for the payment service or other (write a book and insert that in google book api) you should have an API Key (with sign up).
Bye bye

Answer (score 3):

For searching only the informations about books (author, title, etc..) you can write code without have any API key. But sometimes google books API gives back HTTP 403. HTTP Status Code 403: The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. So it is advisable you use the API key generated and also try to mention your country code in it. As sometimes it fails to recognize where the request is coming from so it gives you access denied (403) error.
`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:${bookTitle}&key=${googleKey}&country=${countryName}`
This query was used by me in a React application as sometimes without key or country name i got HTTP 403 error. countryName is of the form `US` or `UK`, etc.

Comment: Also the free google developer key is limited to 1000 search query results per day. So in case you purchase to increase the quota you would obviously require a google API key